# How to make security group see only own contacts in Odoo 15?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-15

I want the security group **User: Own Documents Only** (`sales_team.group_sale_salesman`) to see only own contacts (records from `res.partner` with `user_id` field matching the current user ID).

It's easy to make a rule for that, the problem is that it won't work, because if you belong to `sales_team.group_sale_salesman`, you must belong to `base.group_user` too, and this user can also see almost all contacts, due to the following rule:

- `base.res_partner_rule_private_employee`: it allows to see all contacts which fulfill the domain: `['|', ('type', '!=', 'private'), ('type', '=', False)]`

So if I add a new group rule which sets the domain `[('user_id', '=', user.id)]`, it won't work, because group rules are added with OR, so if doesn't matter if I am the salesperson of a contact or not, if the contact is not private, I'll see it.

Then I thought it would be as easy as modifying the rule `base.res_partner_rule_private_employee` in order to set this `domain_force`:

- `[('user_id', '=', user.id), '|', ('type', '!=', 'private'), ('type', '=', False)]`

But after that, the problem is that every user belonging to `sales_team.group_sale_salesman` (or only `base.group_user`) gets a security error each time they log in, complaining about access to `res.users` model, the surprising thing is that it doesn't blame any rules...

So after that I created a new rule to control that error:

```
<record id="rule_own_users" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">res.users.own.users</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_users"/>
    <field name="domain_force">
        ['|', ('id', '=', user.id), ('partner_id.user_id', '=', user.id)]
    </field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[
        Command.link(ref('base.group_user')),
    ]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

But despite that, I get the same error, this time blaming my new `res.users` rule.

Does anyone know hot to manage my purpose or what is my mistake?

**EDIT**

I guess the problem is that any user needs at least see the partner related to its own user (and may be other like *OdooBot*) and the partners related to the companies he works for. How to add them to a `res.partner` rule?